# RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed! Statsmodels installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cython, statsmodels

When I run `python setup.py` from the source clone of [Statsmodels](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels) in `cmd`, it is throwing the error, although the Cython installed is cython.version '0.27.3'

```
statsmodels-master>python setup.py install
Cythonizing sources
Processing statsmodels\nonparametric\linbin.pyx
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Test\statsmodels-master\tools\cythonize.py", line 215, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Test\statsmodels-master\tools\cythonize.py", line 211, in main
    find_process_files(root_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Test\statsmodels-master\tools\cythonize.py", line 203, in find_process_files
    process(cur_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
  File "C:\Users\Test\statsmodels-master\tools\cythonize.py", line 174, in process
    processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
  File "C:\Users\Test\statsmodels-master\tools\cythonize.py", line 72, in process_pyx
    raise Exception('Cython failed')
Exception: Cython failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 546, in <module>
    generate_cython()
  File "setup.py", line 90, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try debugging before asking?

Comment: This smells like you're passing it a quoted path while it expects a path without quotes.

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint at the line that prints the `"Unable to create process using"`, guess what's wrong with variable values, then track the erroneous value back to its origin.

Comment: I run this file from statsmodel master github repository, git://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels.git .

Comment: When try to install using pip in cmd, it throws 

 Exception: Cython-generated file `'statsmodels/tsa/regime_switching/_hamilton_filter.c' not found.
            Cython is required to compile statsmodels from a development branch.
            Please install Cython or download a source release of statsmodels.`

Although I have installed Cython of version 0.27.3 and python version is 3.5.3

Comment: Maybe your Cython is installed for another Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that the `setup.py` file's path is not matching your python package dependency file's paths.

You can install it using this way instead of using the source code.

```
sudo su
your password
pip install statsmodels
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer and better format it?

Comment: I edited my answer above. Let me know if you have any other question @Mehdi